# Poor performance of NServiceBus over MSMQ

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, nservicebus

We are trying to integrate NServiceBus/MSMQ in our current web application (REST).

Running the profiler, it seems that a **lot** of time is spent sending the message to the queue (see  the profiler screen shot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHMW4.png), were the highlighted 30 is 30% of the overall execution time). It takes about twice the time just to send the message to MSMQ than saving an entire new set of documents in Mongo (running on a remote server).

Is it normal that sending a message to MSMQ queue is that slow or are we missing some configuration tweak?

The following is our current bus configuration (based on NServiceBus documentation - http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/894008-using-nservicebus-with-asp-net-mvc):

```
// NServiceBus configuration
Configure
    .WithWeb()
    .CastleWindsorBuilder(_container)
    .JsonSerializer()
    .Log4Net()
    .MsmqTransport()
    .IsTransactional(false)
    .PurgeOnStartup(true)
    .UnicastBus()
    .ImpersonateSender(false)
    .SendOnly();
```

and web.config:

```
 <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="Error" />
 <MsmqTransportConfig NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5" />
 <UnicastBusConfig>
   <MessageEndpointMappings>
     <add Messages="Messages" Endpoint="MessageHandlers" />
   </MessageEndpointMappings>
 </UnicastBusConfig>
```

[image: Screenshot of ANTS profiler]

Comment: What version on NServiceBus are you on?

Comment: How did u profile this? Was the debugger attached? How many messages did you send?

Comment: @JohnSimons: NSB version is 3.3.5. We profiled it with ANTS profiler, making 25K calls to our API; in each iteration the app both saves a handful of small documents into Mongo and sends a message to the NSB for auditing purposes. Debugger was not attached. 

On a separate machine, without a profiler attached, we also added some timing logs around both NSB and Mongo calls and NSB send operations were consistently slower (sometimes almost 10x slower).

Comment: How many messages per second are you getting? (I get around 4000 msg/s doing plain sends on my machine)

Comment: Are you running mongo locally?

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund: I get about 250 msg/s in a tight loop in a prototype program. Mongo is running remotely. Today I tried the same tight loop with RabbitMQ and I reach 1K+ msg/s.

Comment: Something must be off, I get better send perf(durable messages) out of msmq compared to rabbit on my box?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an [MSMQ issue](http://ayende.com/blog/4251/what-am-i-missing-msmq-perf-issue).
Transactional MSMQ simply isn't optimized for writing to it quickly.